# roslaunch_add_file_check(..) and build dependencies

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having added a `roslaunch_add_file_check(..)` to my `CMakeLists.txt`, I notice that if the tests are invoked as:

```
catkin_make run_tests_my_package
```

in a clean workspace (ie: no `build` or `devel` directories present), all tests that include launchfiles that start compiled nodes fail. catkin immediately tries to execute the tests, without first compiling the package, or any of its dependencies. Example console output:

```
####
#### Running command: "make run_tests_my_package -j1" in "/home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- run_tests.py: execute commands
  /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results/my_package
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/roslaunch/cmake/../scripts/roslaunch-check -o /home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results/my_package/roslaunch-check_tests_roslaunch_test.xml.xml /home/user/ros/catkin_ws/src/my_repo/my_package/tests/roslaunch_test.xml 
checking /home/user/ros/catkin_ws/src/my_repo/my_package/tests/roslaunch_test.xml
...writing test results to /home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results/my_package/roslaunch-check_tests_roslaunch_test.xml.xml
FAILURE:
[/home/user/ros/catkin_ws/src/my_repo/my_package/tests/roslaunch_test.xml]:
    cannot find node [compiled_node_a] in package [some_other_package]
cannot find node [compiled_node_b] in package [my_package]
cannot find node [compiled_node_c] in package [my_package]
wrote test file to [/home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results/my_package/roslaunch-check_tests_roslaunch_test.xml.xml]
-- run_tests.py: verify result "/home/user/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results/my_package/roslaunch-check_tests_roslaunch_test.xml.xml"
Built target run_tests_my_package_roslaunch-check_tests_roslaunch_test.xml
Built target run_tests_my_package_roslaunch-check
Built target run_tests_my_package
```

`my_package` has both run and build depends on `some_other_package` in its `package.xml`. And `roslaunch` is a `build_depend` of `my_package`.

I've tried using `add_dependencies(..)`, but couldn't find a working target. It would also mean I'd have to manually make all targets dependencies of my roslaunch test. Is there a way to make the roslaunch tests only run *after* all other targets have been built?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125676/roslaunch_add_file_check(..)-and-build-dependencies/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The next `roslaunch` version (1.9.55) will allow you to specify the option keyword `DEPENDENCIES` when invoking `roslaunch_add_file_check()` followed by a list of target names which must be built before the test is run.

Until then you must manually build all targets necessary (or just build the whole workspace).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-03**:
If a target local to my pkg is added to the DEPENDENCIES, and my pkg (build)depends on another pkg, will the targets in my dependencies also be build first? In other words: are the dependencies recursive?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-04**:
Build dependencies from the package.xml file do not map to CMake target dependencies automatically since they are very different. If you want to depend on all target packages you depend on are exporting use the catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS variable as an argument. Those are usually used for targets which generate message header etc.